# My facebook "like" function is every time need to login to the facebook. How can I solve it?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I used the following codes in my android app that can "like" to a specific link via facebook. But when I task, it asked me to login even though I already logged into facebook android app and web browser also. I don't know why. Can anybody answer me?

```
 private void appendUrl(String url, String appId,
        FacebookLikeOptions options, StringBuilder sb)
{
    sb.append("<iframe ");
    sb.append("style='");
    sb.append("display:block;clear:both;border:none;overflow:hidden;");
    sb.append("width:100%;");
    sb.append("'");

    sb.append("src='//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php");
    //noinspection deprecation
    sb.append("?href=").append(URLEncoder.encode(url));
    sb.append("&layout=").append(options.getLayoutString());
    sb.append("&action=").append(options.getActionString());
    sb.append("&show_faces=").append(options.showFaces);
    sb.append("&share=").append(options.share);

    if (appId != null && appId.trim().length() > 0)
    {
        sb.append("&appId=").append(appId);
    }

    sb.append("'");

    sb.append("scrolling='no'");
    sb.append("frameborder='0'");
    sb.append("allowTransparency='true'");
    sb.append("></iframe>");
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing because you open it in a webview in your app. That webview will not have any cookies.

Comment: @WizKid So, how to solve this problem? Can I use default facebook API implementation, for example Share Dialog box? Or how to remaining cookies in my android app?